# PHP Changing order and price filters using queries

Tags: php

I am working on a filter for my website and it seems like my logic is running out!
I managed to sort the order of the items based on the selected radio button but I don't know how to integrate the price inputs (From:__ To:__)

in the index.php:

```
$price_range ='';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $lowest_price = $_POST['lowest_price'];
    $highest_price = $_POST['highest_price'];
    $price_range = "`price` BETWEEN LIKE '%" .$lowest_price."%' AND LIKE '%" .$highest_price."%'";
                    }

    $order_list=(isset($_POST['order_list']))?$_POST['order_list']:'';                      
switch($order_list) {
    case "link1":   $order_list_sql = "ORDER BY `date` DESC";       break;
    case "link2":   $order_list_sql = "ORDER BY `price` ASC";       break;
    case "link3":   $order_list_sql = "ORDER BY `price` DESC";      break;
    case "link4":   $order_list_sql = "ORDER BY `id` DESC";         break;
    default:        $order_list_sql = "ORDER BY `date` DESC";   
                    }

$res =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` ".$order_list_sql."    LIMIT 10");
```

In the form.php:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <li>Ad Order
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link1" <?php echo (isset($_POST[ 'order_list'])=='link1' ? 'checked': '')?>>Newest First</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link2" <?php echo (isset($_POST[ 'order_list'])=='link2' ? 'checked': '')?>>Lowest Price First</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link3" <?php echo (isset($_POST[ 'order_list'])=='link3' ? 'checked': '')?>>Highest Price First</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="order_list" value="link4" <?php echo (isset($_POST[ 'order_list'])=='link4' ? 'checked': '')?>>Nearest First</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Price
        <ul>
            <li>From: $
                <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" size="8" name="lowest_price" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lowest_price'])) { echo $_POST['lowest_price']; } ?>">
            </li>
            <li>To: $
                <input type="text" size="8" name="highest_price" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['highest_price'])) { echo $_POST['highest_price']; } ?>">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

**UPDATED:**
what I have tried so far but seems to go right to the else statement

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) === true && empty($_POST['submit']) === false){
    $lowest_price = $_POST['lowest_price'];
    $highest_price = $_POST['highest_price'];
    $price_range = "WHERE `price` BETWEEN ".$lowest_price." AND ".$highest_price."";

    if(empty($_POST['order_list']) === false && $_POST['order_list'] == "link1"){
        $order_list = "ORDER BY `date` DESC";   
    }
    if(empty($_POST['order_list']) === false && $_POST['order_list'] == "link2"){
        $order_list = "ORDER BY `price` ASC";   
    }
    if(empty($_POST['order_list']) === false && $_POST['order_list'] == "link3"){
        $order_list = "ORDER BY `price` DESC";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['order_list']) === false && $_POST['order_list'] == "link4"){
        $order_list = "ORDER BY `id` DESC";     
    }                           
    $res =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` ".$price_range." ".$order_list." LIMIT 10");
}else{
    $res =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10");
}
```

Comment: If you could, better use `mysqli` functions instead of `mysql`, because that last are deprecated

Comment: And please fix your SQL injection vulnerability!

Answer (score 0):

Change $price_range into:

```
$price_range = "WHERE price BETWEEN ".$lowest_price." AND ".$highest_price." ";
```

change $res into

```
$res =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds ".$price_range." ".$order_list_sql."    LIMIT 10");
```

let me know the result..

Comment: this is not a secure way at all! Take a look at [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#!) link

Comment: I tried that before and it gave me errors. and currently, every time I change the order, the order selection radio button isn't checked even though I specified it to be checked. Right now it always puts a check on the last option in the order list